# HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-403

When I start Debugging on asp.net3.5 . Browser display bellow message

*Server Error in '/attn-web' Application.

HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden.

Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 9.0.0.0*

Comment: Yes , When  I Debug program, browser prompt 'Authentication Required' Input Box  with information 'Enter user name and Passord for http://localhost:1169'. and after entering user name and password browser this display above message which is mention before.

Comment: Do you happen to have NOD32 installed and running?

Comment: I think Windows authentication is enabled in web.config.Change it to form

Answer (score 5):

It might be an issue with NTLM Authentication.

1. Right-click on your solution in the Solution Explorer.
2. Select Property Pages.
3. Select Start Options in the dialog.
4. In the Server section, uncheck NTLM Authentication

Answer (score 2):

If you have Vista or Windows 7 try running the Visual Studio as administrator (right click the EXE and choose "Run as administrator") as it might be some security/permissions issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting following issues, after trying their solutions i got this same error message

[WCFTestClient The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044034/wcftestclient-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme) (my service is a non-WCF service)

[The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919912/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-ntlm)

and finally got the solution from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1685336.aspx/1?HTTP+Error+403+Forbidden+) which is **In the Server section, uncheck NTLM Authentication** (Project Properties -> Web -> Servers)

Answer (score 1):

1. Firewall,
2. bad 'hosts' file,
3. aspnet server configuration problem,
4. Folder security restrictions

..

Try to look at log files *(Win+F, select folder /Windows and specify to find fresh files)* and 'Event Viewer' *(Press Win, then type: Event Viewer)*

P.S.: Nothing personal, but your question is really unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. I had moved the project and fetched it again. It turns out that Visual Studio binds the virtual directory name as the source path for the files, and moving a (physical) directory makes IIS adjust the virtual directory to the new path. Visual Studio uses the virtual directory name still, and that causes a conflict.

Deleting in IIS the virtual directory made things work again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. This is how I solved it. I think this may be helpful for you.
1. Go to **"start"** and then type **IIS**(Internet Information Services) and hit Enter
2. In the right side there are **"connections"**
3. Go to **"sites"**-> **"Default Web Site"** which is located inside the connections
4. Double click the "Default website"
5. There in the features view double click the **"Directory Browsing"**
6. In the right side there are the actions if **"Enable"** is available double click on that (Otherwise that feature is all ready available)
7. Then go back to the previous page
8. Double click on **"Default Document"**
9. There you can see a list of default documents
10. If your default document for the website is not available you can add it by clicking the **"add"** in the right side and there type the name of your default document.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to change the specific port you are using:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer.

   Go to
   Properties.

   Select Web in the dialog.

   Change the Specific port to
   anything else e.g. 44444

hope this is the solution for your problem