# HTTP request is not allowed for client authentication scheme "Ntlm"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919912/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-ntlm) question, but it seems like not my way:(

I have client service (console app), and at server side- Bitrix CMS web-service.
So, all works well , but when i update service someday on my VS 2012 and 
call Send(...) method- i got error:

```
Received from the server authentication header "NTLM". HTTP request is not allowed for client authentication scheme "Ntlm". Received from the server authentication header "NTLM".
```

(it is google translate)

I try to delete and recreate service, restart VS, restart Windows- it is not working.

So, app.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="CTfsTasksWSBinding">
         <security mode ="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://server.domen.local/tfs_tasks_ws.php"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CTfsTasksWSBinding"
    contract="Bitrix.CTfsTasksWSInterface" name="CTfsTasksWSSoap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel> 
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source = |SQL/CE|" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So, my code:

```
 Bitrix.CTfsTasksWSInterfaceClient cll = new Bitrix.CTfsTasksWSInterfaceClient();
 cll.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new  System.Net.NetworkCredential(loginn, passwd);
 cll.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
```

I create new simple console app and paste some code from main app- i have the same error.

Please help me to fix this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not valid password. 
All works.